# how to write a script to get ifInOctets and ifOutOctets?

Tags: scripting, snmp, shell-scripting, snmpd

Can any one help me with   writing a script to get ifInOctets and ifOutOctets from a server 10.38.2.24 ?

I need help

Answer (score 1):

snmpget -v 2c -c PUBLIC 10.38.2.24 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10

snmpget -v 2c -c PUBLIC 10.38.2.24 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.16

-c communityname, default to PUBLIC

-v version, probably 2c

[SNMPget: Net-SNMP](http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/TUT:snmpget)

Comment: Probably want snmpwalk instead of snmpget to get all the interfaces of each (arguments would be the same)